# how to get one row out of 3 rows where all columns have same id but other data is not same

Tags: mysql, database, oracle

```
SELECT
    isbn13,
    MAX(TITLE) as TIT,
    MAX(PUBLISHER) as PUB,
   MAX(PUBLICATION_DATE)as P_DATE,
   MAX(PUBLICATION_COUNTRY_LOCATION) as P_C_LOC,
   MAX(BISAC_CODES) as B_CODES,
   MAX(BIC_SUBJECT_CODE)as B_S_CODES,
   MAX(FLEXFIELD2) as B_style,
   MAX(FLEXFIELD3) as lam_type,
   MAX(FLEXFIELD5) as color_text,
   MAX(FLEXFIELD6) as cover_color,
   MAX(FLEXFIELD7) as paper_type,
   MAX(FLEXFIELD8) as GSM,
   MAX(FLEXFIELD9) as casing,
   MAX(FLEXFIELD10) as spine,
   MAX(FLEXFIELD10) as thickness,
   MAX(FLEXFIELD12) as height,
   MAX(FLEXFIELD13) as width,
   MAX(PAGE_COUNT) as P_count
FROM
    (select isbn13,TITLE,PUBLISHER,PUBLICATION_DATE,PUBLICATION_COUNTRY_LOCATION,BISAC_CODES,BIC_SUBJECT_CODE,
    FLEXFIELD2,FLEXFIELD3,FLEXFIELD5,FLEXFIELD6,FLEXFIELD7,FLEXFIELD8,FLEXFIELD9,FLEXFIELD10,FLEXFIELD12,FLEXFIELD13,PAGE_COUNT,
     ROWNUM as rn from(select * from catalog_master ORDER BY cat_id ASC)
    union
    select isbn13,TITLE,PUBLISHER,PUBLICATION_DATE,PUBLICATION_COUNTRY_LOCATION,BISAC_CODES,BIC_SUBJECT_CODE,
    FLEXFIELD2,FLEXFIELD3,FLEXFIELD5,FLEXFIELD6,FLEXFIELD7,FLEXFIELD8,FLEXFIELD9,FLEXFIELD10,FLEXFIELD12,FLEXFIELD13,PAGE_COUNT,
    rownum as rn from (select * from sec_catalog_master ORDER BY cat_id ASC)
    )
where rn>0 and rn<=100
GROUP BY isbn13
ORDER BY isbn13 ASC
```

I have a table in the database where the id is unique but at the source end, the id is duplicate. the data available concerning that duplicate id is not the same. so I want to get one row from those duplicates id.

I tried to use the MAX and MIN function in SQL but that will give me bad data.

I expect the result like when I run the query. I want the data where I get one row out of these all duplicates.

Comment: See creating a [mcve]

Comment: It appears that you require a fairly simple SQL query. However it is impossible for me to provide it, due to the dearth of details. What is the name of the database table? What are the names and data-types of the columns in that table? At least post the SQL you tried. Also _MySQL_ and _Oracle_ are two separate database management systems (DBMS). Are you using both? Do you need a [SQL] query for both? Do you think the same query can be used for both? Please also post sample data and expected result.

Comment: And down-voting the question, while extremely easy to do, does not help the OP - who is a new contributor - to understand why his question is not a good question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the analytic `row_number()` function to do this, something like:

```
select id,
       col2,
       col3,
       ...
       orderby_col
from   (select yt.id,
               yt.col2,
               yt.col3, 
               ...
               yt.orderby_col
               row_number() over (partition by yt.id order by yt.orderby_col) rn
        from   your_table)
where  rn = 1;
```

This works by grouping the data into sets using the column (could be multiple columns) in the `partition by` clause, and then applying a row number to them in the order specified by the column(s) in the `order by` clause.

Once you have each set of ids labeled, you can then just select the first row from each group.